# dividing large data sets in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I need to convert the large data sets of mongodb to CSV. For that i decided to use the `async.queue` with **concurrency level= no of core**. sample code looks like

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, cb) {
collection.find(query).skip(task.skip).limit(task.limit)
    .toArray(function (err, docs) {
            // convert that data to CSV and push them in a Array
    })
}, cores);

var offset = 0;
var limit = count / cores;
for (; cores >= 0; cores--) {
    q.push({skip: offset, limit: limit});
    offset += limit
}
// return the result after everything is done
q.drain = function () {
    callback(inMemoryCsv.join())
};
```

But mongo docs says that **skip** is very expensive in `mongodb`. So what can i do in this type of situation..?

It is a Rest endpoint where user is making a request to download the CSV. Basically all is real time.

m i doing this in a right way...? Any alternative approach..?

Comment: For pain csv export, I'd use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/). If you have specific requirements, please add them to your question by editing it.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Updated the question. Its a rest endpoint. I mean real time Download